# Testing if a vector is in a population of vectors

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose that I have an object that has N different scalar qualities, each of which I've measured (for example, the (x,y) coordinates at the tips of the major arms of a leaf). Together, I have N such measurements for each object, which I'll save as a 1D list of N reals.

Now I'm given a large number R of such objects, each with its corresponding N-element list. Let's call this the population. We can represent this as a matrix M with R rows, each of N elements.

I'm now given a new object B, with its 1D N-element list. I'd like to hand Mathematica my matrix M and my new object B, and get back a single number that tells me how confident I can be that B belongs to the population represented by M.

I'd also be happy with a probability, or any other number with a simple interpretation. I'm willing to assume that everything is uncorrelated, that the values in columns of M are normally distributed, and other such typical assumptions.

When N=1, Student's t-test seems the right tool. There seem to be tools built into Mathematica that can solve precisely this problem when N>1, but the documentation (and web references) presume more statistical depth than I have, so I don't have confidence that I know what to do. I feel like the solution is tantalizingly just out of reach. If anyone can provide a code example that solves this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your question suggests that you need statistical help before you need Mathematica help and that your question would be better asked elsewhere, perhaps on http://stats.stackexchange.com/?as=1.  If you tell us the algorithm you are trying to implement we can help with the Mathematica programming.

Comment: Thank you, HP Mark! I've taken your advice and have already received some good advice. I'll return if I need programming help once I have a specific algorithm to implement.

Comment: I've followed up with a more precise programming question here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434404/distance-to-a-multivariatestatistics-median[/link]